# How can I aggregate information from about 30 Drupal sites in one place?

Tags: nodes

I have about 30 websites on Drupal. I'm looking for module or service where i can aggregate information from all websites in one place. I need information about number of nodes, comments, users, Drupal core and modules versions. Something like acquia insight but for more sites and cheaper :)

Answer (score 4):

The Similar Module Review's [Administration module wiki](http://groups.drupal.org/node/116609) lists several options.

The following show some usage statistics, as well as Drupal core and module updates:

- [Droptor](http://drupal.org/project/droptor) (Requires [paid service](http://www.droptor.com) for more than 1 site.)
- [Drupal Remote Dashboard](http://drupal.org/project/drd)
- [Network Manager](http://drupal.org/project/network_manager) (Drupal 7 version [doesn't exist yet](http://drupal.org/node/1150368).)
- [Sentry Server](http://drupal.org/project/sentry_server) (Drupal 7 version [doesn't exist yet](http://drupal.org/node/1700142).)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Droptor](http://www.droptor.com/tour#site-list). And the corresponding [Droptor module](http://drupal.org/project/droptor).

30 websites looks like $696/year (the first one is free)

Answer (score 2):

I have good experience with the [Production monitor](http://drupal.org/project/prod_check) project.

The prod_check server module is enabled in the master site, while the prod_check client module is enabled in all sites. You may tracks modules, alerts, and even performance to verify that the tracked sites are in a good working state.

It's  not as extensive as acquia insight, but the module has an API which allows you to extend it to provide more metrics.

Comment: Production monitor is awesome, but it doesn't provide usage statistics (which the OP requested).

Comment: He can write a simple module to add it. It will still be cheaper...

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it). It can be used to query the data in other databases. Various DBMS formats are supported, such as another Drupal database also (which your question appears to be about).

Here is how to get you going:

- Install/enable the Forena module.
- Define a [Data Source](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.data#datasources) (= database connection) for each of your 30 Drupal sites, probably using a name that reflects each of those sites.
- Use "FrxDrupal" as the "Driver" for the Data Source, to indicate it is a Drupal database.
- Start from the delivered reports in category "Drupal Administration" to clone/enhance them to fit your needs (e.g. the one titled "Enabled Modules and Themes"). And make them use any of the 30 Data Sources (instead of the Drupal Database of the site where you installed Forena).

#### More info about Forena

Forena is built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports. For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link `/reports/help`.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link `/reports/samples` (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).